# shell commands of node modules not in path on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, node.js

On Ubuntu, if I install a module like:

```
npm install nodemon -g
```

I have the command `nodemon` in the `$path`

On Mac OSX, `nodemon` is not in `$path`...

Any clues?

UPDATE: there is nothing `/usr/local/bin`, I also tried the same result with `npm install nodemon -g`

Answer (score 6):

Try installing it globally:

```
sudo npm install nodemon -g
```

If that doesn't work either, add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH`.

Comment: thanks, I did use the -g flag at first, ... same results (no command in path)

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo npm install nodemon -g`? Also, what does `npm prefix -g` say?

Comment: sudo npm install nodemon -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/nodemon -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/nodemon/nodemon.js
nodemon@0.7.8 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/nodemon

Comment: It seems to be installing it in `/usr/local/share/npm/bin`, which isn't right. How did you install Node/npm?

Comment: No problem :) Try using [the official Mac installer](http://nodejs.org/download/), it hasn't given me any issues yet.

Comment: uninstalling (the brew install) and reinstalling node (UPDATE : uninstalling the brew and installing http://nodejs.org/download/ solved it

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my Mac. I was able to solve this by installing globally (no sudo required) and then adding `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` to my path. It's easy to put this in your bash profile so it gets added at startup. First, vim ~/.bash_profile, then:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

Then everything works as expected.

Incidentally, when I echo $PATH, /usr/local/bin is there, so it must be an issue with how npm works on Mac (that is, the global install location is different for Mac than Linux).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using fish shell, and installed node via homebrew, add this to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```
set PATH /usr/local/Cellar/node/6.6.0/bin/ $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

have you updated your terminal path since installing? Try closing and reopening your terminal. Are you using nvm (node version manager)? If so the binaries will be in something like

```
Users/maxl/.nvm/v0.10.4/bin
```

What is the output of

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for a while. Then I discovered that the project I was working on had its own RVM gemset. The node module I was trying to install was `npm install -g grunt-contrib-compass`.

The result was that when I opened a new terminal window and ran `which compass` I would see the path, great! But after a cd to my project directory the path would be gone???
It turns out that NPM will install gems to RVM's (default) gemset! I tried to re-install without the -g flag and no luck.

My solution was a quick `rvm --force gemset delete appname` and just used the default for the project. Probably not ideal, but it worked.  Hope this hint helps others.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what worked for me was using nvm, and then doing :

```
nvm install stable
nvm use stable
nvm alias default stable
```

I realized that after running `npm config get prefix` and seeing it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Binary or symlink to it or to executable might be in path `/Users/[username]/private/node_modules/.bin`

For example:

`ls -l /Users/[username]/private/node_modules/.bin/json-server  lrwxr-xr-x  1 [username]  group  29 Oct  9 14:29 /Users/[username]/private/node_modules/.bin/json-server -> ../json-server/lib/cli/bin.js`

Adding line `PATH="$PATH:/Users/[username]]/private/node_modules/.bin/"` to `~/.bash_profile` file and running `source /Users/[username]]/.bash_profile` should cause the same behaviour you experience in Ubuntu